# Clojure: transform list of pairs/n-tuples into n-tuple of lists

Tags: list, vector, clojure, clojurescript

Given a list of an n-tuple,

```
[[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"]]
```

I would like to obtain

```
[[1, 2, 3]["a", "b", "c"]]
```

I think this is probably available as a function in the std. library, like it is in python `zip(*lst)`. But I could not find it unfortunately.

Otherwise i guess I can come up with an implementation using a reduce, etc. But I would prefer a standard clojure function :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(apply map vector [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"]])
```

if you need a vector you can use `mapv`:

```
(apply mapv vector [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"]])
```